# Pass query and html from views to modal popup

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have background page:

views:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html')
```

and html:

```
{% extends 'app/basenobar.html' %}
{%load staticfiles %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
{% block content %}


<body>
<a href="#" id="winOpener2">Open PopUp</a>
```

Now, if I click on the button it open popup and everything work but I need to pass a query from view to popup body

For example, I have a query in a view:

```
@login_required
def myquery(request):
    family = Books.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/myquery.html', {family:'family'})
```

and a popup html:

```
<div id="window2" title="Test Window">
{% for member in family %}
{{ member.pk }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

and I need to pass this values inside my popup when I click for open it.

At the end I need to render my popup from view.

Any idea?
TY

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax. Just have ajax send a request to the server to a secondary url and then have a secondary view specifically for the popup and have it return the template for the popup. That should allow you to have the popup have a fresh query every time the user loads the popup.